# Maya Mel Script - How to get bottom point of model?

Tags: mel

How to get bottom point of model via Mel script?
[image: Maya Bottom Point]

If I can get the Y-coordinate of the bottom point, I can get the point of the bottom, but I can't figure out how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through all vertices can be slow, especially with a dense mesh. What can be done instead is to use the object's bounding box:

```
float $bb[] = `getAttr pCube1.boundingBoxMin`;
print($bb[1]); // Lowest position in Y
```

Another benefit of this is that you aren't relying on vertices, so it doesn't have to be a polygonal mesh.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find the document for: boundingBoxMin, boundingBoxMax,... I want to know more about these attributes that I can access.

Comment: You can view most of them in the connection editor (with show non-keyable). You can also use `listAttr` to display them via script.

Comment: Hi, I found a problem with this method. When I select multiple objects, it can't get boundingBoxMin for each object, please check this demo to see what I'm talking about: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14h0Misc_aUh1lRnvyo47IfeU8U9X59eo

Comment: It's the way you're querying `minBox`. If you print it out it's getting the same values. This gets the proper values as expected: $minBox = `getAttr ($item + ".boundingBoxMin");`

Answer (score 0):

> If I can get the Y-coordinate of the bottom point, I can get the point of the bottom, but I can't figure out how to get it.

I figure it out: Y-coordinate of the bottom point = Y-coordinate of the lowest vertex of the model. So do it like this: Loop through all vertices to get the lowest vertex.

Assume the target object is: "pCube1". Here is the code to get the lowest Y.

```
int $vtxIdx;
int $vCount[] = `polyEvaluate -vertex pCube1`; //Get vertex count
float $lowestY = 2147483647.0;
float  $crtY = 0.0;
for ($vtxIdx = 0; $vtxIdx < $vCount[0]; $vtxIdx++)//Loop through vetex
{
    float $pos[] = `xform -q -ws -t ("pCube1.vtx["+$vtxIdx+"]")`;//Get vertex position
    $crtY = $pos[1];
    if($crtY < $lowestY)
    {
        $lowestY = $crtY;//Get the lowest Y
    }
}
print ($lowestY);
```

So the lowest point = (pCube1.X, lowestY, pCube1.Z).